# Is my queueing theory question completely misunderstood?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[My question on queuing theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653891/can-you-explain-the-queueing-question-answer-in-this-mba-exam) has been closed as "not about mathematics".  It references a paper about ChatGPT, but that is completely incidental to the question.

The question and associated answer is [presented in a paper](https://mackinstitute.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Christian-Terwiesch-Chat-GTP-1.24.pdf) written about ChatGPT. No content included in the question was generated  ChatGPT, all was produced by those who set the exam, those who wrote the paper and me.  The answer given in a well referenced paper seems highly unintuitive to me, and seems worthy of a question.

Many comments seem to think that some of this is from ChatGPT.  I have tried to make it clear in the question but it is clear I have failed.  Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong?

Comment: The post is just reopened.

Comment: I highly recommend that you not mention ChatGPT if it is not germane to the mathematical question you want to ask. I guess there are places where having a ChatGPT connection will attract positive attention, but I'm pretty sure it's the opposite here.